# Does MongoDB have a limit for referencing related objects?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, limit, bson

I have a database with many records where each record is relatively small, the problem is that I have other documents that relate many records, for example, each product that is associated with a company. If each MongoDB document is limited to a maximum document size, does this include the identifier relationship references variable? Does this mean that MongoDB has a maximum limit to which an object can be referenced 1 to 1? Or does MongoDB not include this data within the limit?

If the limit affects the size of the references, does this mean that I will only be able to maintain the relationship from the individual record to the master but not from the master to the individual? Wouldn't this affect product searches by store?

Comment: Have you checked out the patterns in [this official blog](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design)?